# Android: Facebook login isn't working from another phone

Tags: android, facebook

I'm testing android with facebook login example (SessionLoginSample) and its working on my phone but it's not working from another phones.
The pop up shows up but it does nothing when i clicked OK.
It should have shown facebook login after i clicked OK. anyone knows what's wrong?

```
private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            textInstructionsOrLink.setText(URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS + session.getAccessToken());
            buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.logout);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
            });
        } else {
            textInstructionsOrLink.setText(R.string.instructions);
            buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.login);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you installing your app on other phones? If you're building an apk with a release keystore, then you'll have a different key hash, which you would need to add to your app settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the key id must be replaced by the key id that we get from facebook and set the application to be available for all users